# Header struct in double linked list does not work, maybe addNode function wrong?

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a double linked list in C, my Data is a struct with previous/next pointer and 1float / 2 char arrays,

So i am assuming to create a list i need to define/ dreate a header struct, which i am doing in the main.
Unfortunately i can not add the List-Element with my "AddNode" function and im 90% sure the problem is in the header...

Thank you for your help in advance!

**Here the main function where i try do declare the header**

```
int main()
{
    int abfrage;

    struct header* h;
    h->cnt = 0;
    h->first = NULL;
    h->last = NULL;

    do{
        printf("Aktion eingeben: 1- AddNode 2-AddnodeafterVal 3-removeLastNode 4-removeNodeAfterVal 5-resetList 6-Stop\n");
        scanf("%d", &abfrage);

        if(abfrage==1) //addNode
        {
            struct node* newNode = createNode(); //Daten eingeben und Node erstellen
            struct node* addedNode = addNode(h, newNode); //Node wird zur liste hinzugefügt
            if(!addedNode) printf("Error!");
        }
```

**Here the Header and Node struct**

```
struct node
{
    struct node* prev;
    char name[40];
    float price;
    char material[20];
    struct node*next;
};


struct header
{
    struct node * first;
    int cnt;
    struct node * last;
};
```

**Here the functions**
The enter Data function just gets the Input Data, create Node ... -> addNode should add the element to the list, i think the problem could be here:

```
struct node * enterData(float price, char name[], char material []) //funktion um node zu erstellen, NOCH NICHT VERBUNDEN
{
    struct node * newNode = (struct node*) calloc (1,sizeof(struct node)); //neuer Speicher vom typ NODE allokieren, enth�lt 2 pointer und struct piece

    if(newNode!=NULL)   //wenn newNode erstellt wurde
    {
        newNode->price=price;    //piece einf�gen in NODE
        strcpy(newNode->material, material);
        strcpy(newNode->name, name);
        return newNode;             //newNode zur�ckgeben
    }else{
        return NULL;                //wenn Node NULL ist wieder rausgehen, FEHLER
    }

};


struct node * addNode (struct header* h, struct node * newNode)
{
    if(h->cnt == 0)//wenn noch kein element da ist
    {
        h->first = newNode;
        h->last = newNode;
        h->cnt++;
        newNode->next=NULL;
        newNode->prev=NULL;
    }else
    {
        h->last->next=newNode; //hier wird "next" Pointer vom alten "last" auf das neue Element gesetzt
        //man muss �ber h->last->next damit man element anf�gen kann
        h->last=newNode;//hier wird neues "last" definiert
        h->cnt++; //header count erhöhen für jedes neu erstellte element
        newNode->prev=h->last;
        newNode->next=NULL;
    }
    return newNode;
};
struct node * createNode()
{
    char tempname[40];
    float tempprice;
    char tempmaterial[20];

    //---- Daten Abfrage
    printf("\nBitte Preis eingeben:");
    scanf("%f", &tempprice);
    printf("\nBitte Name eingeben:");
    scanf("%s", tempname);
    printf("\nBitte Material eingeben:");
    scanf("%s", tempmaterial);
    //---Node wird erstellt
    struct node * newNode =enterData(tempprice, tempname, tempmaterial);

    return newNode;
};
```

Comment: Your `addNode` function is incomplete.  It is not setting either the `prev` or `next` pointers in `newNode`, i.e. it needs to set `newNode->prev` and `newNode->next`.  In general, adding a node to the list requires setting 4 pointers:  2 pointers that point to the new node, and 2 pointers that point from the new node.  You're only setting 2 of the 4.

Comment: It looks like you've made some changes since the original post, so my comments may or may not apply at this point.  In general, you should avoid making changes to your posted code, since it makes existing comments (and answers) somewhat meaningless.

Comment: Ok, the changes to `addNode` are almost right, but still buggy.  When you set `newNode->prev=h->last`, you're picking up the new value of `h->last`, which is `newNode`.  You need to set `newNode->prev` *before* changing `h->last`.  Just move the `newNode` updates to the beginning of the code block.

Comment: So what's the state of this after all the edits? Is the question still relevant?

Comment: yes, it is still relevant, i added the element pointers in the addNode function

Comment: the problem is that the header initialising or the adding of an element to thr header does not work